# Using arcgisimage along with python basemap

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps, matplotlib-basemap

I am utilizing maps provided through the ArcGIS rest service when i plot information in Python, but have some problems understanding the different options I have when I request I map. The documentation is really really sparse.

First, here is my code:

```
map = Basemap(epsg=3395,
llcrnrlon=27.692793, llcrnrlat=70.390829,
urcrnrlon=28.728254, urcrnrlat=70.855549)
map.arcgisimage(service='World_Topo_Map', xpixels=4000, xsize=16000, verbose= True)
```

This, for some reason leaves me with a topographic map where only the bottom half have good resolution, while the rest is really lacking. Anyone got experience in using this, and know what I do wrong?

This is the resulting http call (from the function above), and you can also see what I describe (half of the image is high resolution, half is low). Warning, large file.

http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/export?bbox=3082747.6154,11156828.0966,3198014.60666,11312643.9336&bboxSR=3395&imageSR=3395&size=8000,8000&dpi=96&format=png32&f=image